# Javascript - make sure one script is done before next is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have a webpage where there are a few javascripts that does the following:

- Starts a gallery slider
- Starts a responsive image grid
- Scrolls to a specific div based on a hashtag in the URL

The problem is that the page scrolls to the DIV before the other two are done, resulting in an offset I can't possibly know beforehand. So I need to make sure the first two scripts are done and all animations are complete before scrolling to the IDs.

I have researched callbacks, and done a lot of googling. But I'm not sure I understand it all. So I'll need an actual working example. I've tried to separate the scripts into several functions, the way I'd normally do it in vbscript. But I'm just learning javascript, and this is something I really need to understand before moving on I think.

Basically this is what I want to accomplish:

```
$(function () {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        startSliderAndGrid();
    });
});

function startSliderAndGrid() {
    //initialize slider
    $('#home-slider').someSliderPlugin();
    $('.simpleslide').someOtherPlugin();
    scrollToID();

}

function scrollToID() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var hashtag = window.location.hash;
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hashtag).offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

So on document.ready I want to start the first function, initialize the plugins, and then move on to scroll to the ID. I've tried using a timeOut function though, and this does work. But I can't predict how long it will take for each system to initialize the plugins. So that's probably not the ideal solution.

Again, sorry if this is really basic (which it probably is), but I need to get this into my head sooner than later :)

Comment: does `someSliderPlugin` and `someOtherPlugin`  have callback method?

Comment: Not that I know of. I've looked through the documentation and I can't find anything on it. I do however have access to each of the scripts, although they're minified. Does this mean that javascript runs asynchronously by default?

Comment: Seems like you have to look into the plugins. JS is single threaded. So the plugins are using some async functions. Have a look into them, try to factor out a callback or a promise/deferred result of the initialize function.

Comment: yes javascript runs asynchronously. Look in to your someSliderPlugin() and someOtherPlugin if they provide callback method. Can you provide links to those plugins?

Comment: I see. Well, I'm using MegafolioPro and I looked through the documentation and couldn't find anything on callback, complete, done or anything like that. I'm sure if I had more knowledge on javascript, I'd be able to find it easily though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a bit more, I found that [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) suits my needs just perfectly :)
In the plugin, I just add a

```
$('.object').promise().done(function() {
   // do other stuff
   myFunction();
});
```

This is perfect when waiting for multiple animations to complete before doing something else.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should write something like an Interceptor:

```
var pluginName=jQuery.fn.Plugin;
jQuery.fn.Plugin=function(param1, param2){
     //throw custom Event
    return pluginName.call(this, param1, param2);
}
```

And after your custom event is thrown continue with the next plugin.

Comment: This seems promising :) Would this need to be put inside a function? Care to elaborate a bit? Using my code from the first post?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function startSliderAndGrid() {
var hashtag = window.location.hash;
$('.simpleslide').someOtherPlugin();
$('#home-slider').someSliderPlugin().parents('body').animate({scrollTop: $(hashtag).offset().top}, 500);
}
```